# Admin panel is not login or not showing invalid credentials error in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

I have an issue that in my magento website admin panel is not logging in with correct username and password and also not showing any error message of invalid login with incorrect credentials.

So please let me know how I resolve the issues of admin login.

Thanks

Comment: You have to reset admin password from database.

Comment: try with other browser.....

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But nothing happen when reset password. And main thing is that its not showing any error like invalid credentials or invalid username and password. I think it may cause of sessions generate error. So please suggest me how I resolve this issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can login to phpmyadmin,  search for  "admin_user" field & click on that and choose MD5 and give new password & save it.

**step 1** : Login to Phpmyadmin & select proper database

**step 2:** : search for admin_user

[image]

**step 3** : click on admin_user

[image]

**step 4** : select MD5 from dropdown and type new password

[image]

**step 5** : click on "Go" button

[image]

you can find detailed explaination [here](https://www.atwix.com/magento/reset-admin-password-mysql/) .

Answer (score 0):

This types of problems occures when magento fails to get domain(mainly in case of localhost). During login magento tries to create cookie. You can wether cookies are forming or not from your web browser. If it is not forming then you have to make some changes in varien.php file.

Find the following file.
    app\code\local\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php

and overide it in local(make required folders if not there). Then find

```
if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
$cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();
}
```

Simply change the condition to

```
if (isset($cookieParams['domain']) && !in_array("127.0.0.1", self::getValidatorData())) {
$cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();
}
```

main reason of doing so is to disable domain check if running on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed the above issue by following these steps.

1- Go to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/session/abstract/varien.php

2- Go to line number 95 and comment out the cookieParams array and define $cookieParams as an array like below

```
// session cookie params
/*$cookieParams = array(
    'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
    'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
    'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
    'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
    'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);*/
$cookieParams = array();
```

This will allow you to log in. 
3- Then go to admin panel check configuration, System->Configuration->web->session & cookie management in that the HTTP control set from Yes to No. Clear or set the proper path.

Hope this answer will help you.